# How does int work in Java math equations?

Tags: java, int, double

I've been reviewing my Java for a class I've taken for the whole year and haven't been doing well on. They have a separate review book called "Be Prepared." I want to see if I get the math behind this line.

```
result = (1 / 2) * n * (n + 1);    // result is 0.0
```

The thing is, this is basic basic basic. I need to know if I'm actually getting this. It looks like my like (1/2) is 0.5. That cast to an int is 0. That's why the whole thing is 0.0.

Am I right?

This book is how you get ready for the AP test. Anyone done eimacs who can help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fahrenheit to Celsius conversion yields only 0.0 and -0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325882/fahrenheit-to-celsius-conversion-yields-only-0-0-and-0-0)

Comment: it's an integer division, not floating point division then truncating down

Comment: If n is an int, then the result should be 0, not 0.0, unless result is of type double.

Answer (score 7):

(1 / 2) will return zero. both are integer and as per integer calculation it will return zero.

Try

```
result = (1.0 / 2) * n * (n + 1);
```

Please have a look at :

- [Division of integers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java)
- [How do math equations work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134493/how-do-math-equations-work-in-java)

---

> In Java the result of each operation is decided by the higher type involved in calculation. It doesn't matter in what type are you assigning the result.

for e.g

```
double d = 10/3;
```

the value of d will be 3.0 only not 3.33.

Comment: he's not actually looking to make this work, he just wants confirmation that his thinking is correct. it's a strange question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and note that `999 / 1000` will also return `0`. It's truncation, not rounding down.